# I am trying to create multiple charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-analytics

with this dataset I am trying to plot by device category  using the ggplot as below and I keep getting the following error message (geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?)
I tried using group= 1 but that didnt work ..any help much aprreciated ?

```
head(gaDataExt)
      date deviceCategory users sessions pageviews
1 20171130        desktop     6        6        10
2 20171130         mobile    14       14        18
3 20171130         tablet     1        1         1
4 20171129        desktop    12       13        15
5 20171129         mobile    29       30        33
6 20171129         tablet     4        5         8

# multiple plots faceted by device categry.
ggplot(data = gaDataExt, mapping = aes(x = date, y = sessions),group = NULL ) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(deviceCategory ~ .) +
  theme_bw() +
  ylim(0,NA)
```

Comment: Using R v.3.4.2 and `tidyverse` v.1.2.0 (`dplyr` v.0.7.4) and `ggplot2` v2.2.1 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(rep(20171130, 3), rep(20171129, 3)),
                 deviceCategory = c('desktop', 'mobile', 'tablet'),
                 users = c(6, 14, 1, 12, 29, 4),
                 sessions = c(6, 14, 1, 13, 30, 5),
                 pageviews = c(10, 18, 1, 15, 33, 8))
```

You can change to months easily using `lubridate`. This gives you the mean by month.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date),
         month = month(date)) %>% 
  group_by(deviceCategory) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, sessions)) + geom_point() + 
      facet_grid(deviceCategory~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

Update, you could simply remove the mean and use the date:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, sessions)) + geom_point() + 
      facet_grid(deviceCategory~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: ok so that works..my point is more that it currently plots out every data point on the X axis but i only want labels per month and year as opposed to every day which is horrible to display .how to display say year and month

Comment: maybe its easier to show you the current output so you can see my issue...instead iof every single ymd listed in the x axis i just want say every mth..as the dataset is from 30/11/16 -30/11/17